# Can I use HTML based theme in wordpress

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I've been trying to create different themes in wordpress but it seems difficult to me as it requires some core functions of Php which I am unable to understand. Now I want to ask the question in details whether we can convert HTML theme to wordpress theme? I know that every theme is made in HTML but what If I make a theme in HTML/CSS or even bootstrap. How to integrate it with wordpress Posts and Pages thing? How can I tell wordpress that when a user adds a post through wordpress, it should go here or wherever? I think the question is vague but I myself is confused. Please do let me know if you understood! Thanks

Comment: this will help to you . https://pinegrow.com/docs/wordpress/convert-html-to-wordpress-theme.html

Comment: Incredibly broad question. You should ask help with a _specific issue_. You should do some more indepth research first, then return here when you have a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a combination of PHP, HTML, and CSS (at the least) to create a WordPress theme.  Luckily, the PHP requried for a basic theme is pretty simple.  I'd like to refer you to: https://www.siteground.com/tutorials/wordpress/wordpress_create_theme.htm .  It gives a basic overview on theme development where the PHP isn't too involved.